# Is this resume question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition

My question is specifically about this question:  [Resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95308/different-projects-at-the-same-company-break-them-apart-on-the-resume-or-keep)

> I have had two very different projects over my years at the company.
>   I'd like to break it into two different blocks on my resume, but there
>   are two reasons I'm considering not to. 1) I had the same job title
>   for both, though the job and project were different. 2) I think
>   recruiters may look at the top block, see that it's only a year long,
>   and not bother to look at the rest. They'll never learn that I was at
>   the company for more than a year.
>
> What's the best way to handle this?

To me this is clearly a VTC off topic question, but maybe I am missing something.  Is this question really on topic and if so how?

Comment: You wrote "because we are not a resume writing service". But the answers to many similar questions indicate that we are indeed a "resume writing *helper* service".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, this is definitely on topic.**

First, to quote the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), allowed topics include (emphasis mine):

> Finding employment (**resumes/cv/cover letters**, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)

Second, as the OP pointed out in a comment, there is a [very large precedent](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) for questions asking about resume formatting and content. Most of these questions, including the one you are asking about, are at their core questions about effectively and concisely communicating information.

You're right that we are not a resume writing service, but that response usually applies to broad questions of *"I'm trying to get job XYZ. What should my resume look like?"* The questions we do allow are those that ask a clear and specific question with specific answers. The question you link is one of those. The OP poses a specific problem that is not dependent on the industry, the specific position, or the OP. There are plenty of other questions asking about how to write confusing job titles in resumes. "[How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)", "[How to list contracting on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-list-contracting-on-resume)", "[Listing a renamed company on a resume or in a cover letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/listing-a-renamed-company-on-a-resume-or-in-a-cover-letter)". All of these fall under questions asking "How do I write XYZ complicated scenario on my resume?"

Comment: Very helpful.  The more I participate, the less I find I know.

Comment: Exactly this. To illustrate the difference: "*I worked at X, Y and Z. What should my resume look like?*" is off-topic. "*I worked at a single company over many years in two drastically different roles, can I list these separately?*" is on-topic. There's some overlap in phrasing of course but generally it should be obvious whether it's "write my resume for me" or "what's the best practice in a general situation?".

Comment: @Lilienthal IMHO all of these resume related questions are completely off topic, there is so much online info about this it isn't even funny.  So my solution is I will just ignore them, since I am apparently in the minority regarding this topic. ( I won't down-vote or VTC ).

Comment: There's info online about anything, I'm not sure why that's relevant? The advantage here is that you have multiple points of view when a question has several answers and those answers undergo feedback and a "grade" in the form of community votes. Because of that I'll look at advice on how to note something on my resume from this site when I wouldn't even consider doing so on Quora or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: @Lilienthal Its relevant because of the amount of obvious pre-written examples that are easily google-able.  As I mentioned I will just ignore them.

Comment: @MisterPositive just wait until you become a moderator, you'll find everything you once thought you knew... is gone! :o

Comment: @enderland I am not sure I am moderator material ;-)